# Latex - hyperref, link to a file.gif

Tags: hyperlink, latex, gif, pdflatex

i want to create a link between my pdf file and a .gif file, is that possible? in Latex i tried with this:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}

\href{run:/./OrbiteEul.gif}{OrbiteEul.gif}
```

but it doesn't work, i mean it create the link, but when you click it nothing happens, the gif doesn't open! Am i missing something?

Thank you in advance for any kind of help.

edit:

I tried this way, but it didn't even compile.

```
\href{file://Users/Angeloferrari/Università/2°_anno/Calcolo_per_l\'astronomia
/Messina/Porgetti_R/Script/OrbiteEul.gif}{OrbiteEul.gif}
```

Comment: I have never heard of a URL scheme `run:`. Did you maybe mean `file://`? (But `file://` does not work with relative paths.)

Comment: I took it from here [link] (http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Hyperlinks), I'll try using `file://` thank you, can you tell me what's the starting folder? I always use relative paths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use

```
\href{run:./OrbiteEul.gif}{OrbiteEul.gif}
```

(note the missing / right after 'run:')

Comment: Thank you Lanting, i tried, but i have the same problem, it creates the link, but if you click on it the .gif file doesn't open!

Comment: It 'is' the correct syntax. Your pdfreader might however block the executing of local files. Also, I don't have enough points to mark the question as a duplicate, but it has been dealt with extensively here: [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41539/does-hyperref-work-between-two-files/41605#41605]